# Updating placeholder tag when deleting input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using this code to add and delete input fields when necessary but would like to update the placeholder tag when I delete a box. I have included the source for the page to show the functions and any help is greatly appreciated before hand. Thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#add-address").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var numberOfAddresses = $("#form1").find("input[name^='data[address]']").length;
        var label = '<label for="data[address][' + numberOfAddresses + ']">Address ' + (numberOfAddresses + 1) + '</label> ';
        var input = '<input type="text" name="data[address][' + numberOfAddresses + ']" id="data[address][' + numberOfAddresses + ']" placeholder= "Address ' + (numberOfAddresses+1) + '"/>';
        var removeButton = '<button class="remove-address">Remove</button>';
        var html = "<div class='address'>" + label + input + removeButton + "</div>";
        $("#form1").find("#add-address").before(html);
    });
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove-address",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".address").remove();
    //update labels
    $("#form1").find("label[for^='data[address]']").each(function(){
        $(this).html("Address " + ($(this).parents('.address').index() + 1));
    });
});
});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" method="post" action = "h.php">
    <div class="address">
        <label for="data[address][0]">Address 1</label>
        <input type="text" name="data[address][0]" id="data[address][0]" placeholder = "Address 1" />
    </div>
    <button id="add-address">Add address</button>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Which placeholder do you want to change exactly? What to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add one more line to change the input `placeholder` in your `.each` loop.

```
$(document).on("click", ".remove-address",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".address").remove();
    //update labels
    $("#form1").find("label[for^='data[address]']").each(function(){
        $(this).html("Address " + ($(this).parents('.address').index() + 1));
        $(this).next("input").attr("placeholder","Address " + ($(this).parents('.address').index() + 1)); //new line added 

    });
});
```

check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xd8F7/1)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`$(this).html("Address " + ($(this).parents('.address').index() + 1));`

You should do this

`$(this).attr("placeholder", "Address " + ($(this).parents('.address').index() + 1));`

Remember, `placeholder` is an attribute of the input tag, not the html content of it.